# Trouble unpacking tuple in python

Tags: python, tuples

I want the location to appear when I ask for results. Why can't I display the employee of the month's location?

Code:

```py
work_hours = [("Jao", "Ville", 800), ("Billy", "Jackson St", 400), ("Kevin", "Westside", 500)]

def employee_check(work_hours):
    
    current_max = 0
    employee_of_month = ""
    
    for employee, location, hours in work_hours:
        if hours > current_max:
            current_max = hours
            employee_of_month = employee
        else:
            pass
    
    # return the statement
    return (employee_of_month, location, current_max)

result = employee_check(work_hours)
print(result)
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code - post your actual code!

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but looking at the picture, it is recommended to use a monospace font for programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
current_max = 0
employee_of_month = ''
employee_of_month_location = ''

for employee,location,hours in work_hours:
    if hours > current_max:
        current_max = hours
        employee_of_month = employee
        employee_of_month_location = location
    else:
        pass

return (employee_of_month, employee_of_month_location, current_max)
```

Comment: It's more common to save index of max if single item is complex.

Comment: Absolutely @OlvinRoght - this was just to illustrate to OP what their existing code pattern was missing

Comment: YAY! THE CODE WORKED! THANK YOU VERY MUCH MATE @gvee

Comment: @JaocquinP, but it's not necessary to reinvent the functions. You should learn built-it functions to easy your programming experience with Python

Comment: ah i see. Thanks bro!

Comment: It looks quite strange to see only the body of a function without the header. I understand that you want to be as near as possible to the OP's code, but maybe you can at least consider also removing the parenthesis after the return statement and the `else: pass`, optionally leaving an additional comment.

Answer (score 2):

In this case more convenient is using built-in function [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max), not reinventing its functionality:

```
max(work_hours, key=lambda x: x[2])
```

Since your list consists of items with the same structure and you want to get only the tuple where the third element (the working hours) is maximum, you can use the key argument of the `max` function. You can pass a function there, in this case an anonymous [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) function. It changes the behavior of the `max` function, i.e. changing where exactly to look at the maximum value *(here: the third position of each element in work_hours)*.

This reduces your code a lot as you can see how to use it:

```py
work_hours = [("Jao", "Ville", 800), ("Billy", "Jackson St", 400), ("Kevin", "Westside", 500)]
result = max(work_hours, key=lambda x: x[2])
```

Comment: Instead of your function

Comment: This is a very good solution to OP's question (upvoted it) using minimal built-in functionality. But it would be even better if you elaborate a bit on that or link to the python docu. For a beginner it is not really helpful to understand how to use it and how exactly the problem is solved. Therefore it is generally discouraged to give code-only answers. There are exceptions, but here I think not.

Comment: Thank you, I edited. I sought also the source from CPython, but didn't manage. If you know, where it is located, add, please.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to go down to C-level. I've edited your answer. Please see this as a suggestion and feel free to change or revert it.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def employee_check(work_hours):
    
    current_max = 0
    employee_of_month = ''
    employee_of_month_location = ''

    for employee,location,hours in work_hours:
        if hours > current_max:
            current_max = hours
            employee_of_month = employee
            employee_of_month_location = location
        else:
            pass

    return employee_of_month, employee_of_month_location, current_max
```

Comment: You don't need `else` block, just remove it. Also parentheses is redundant in your `return` statement.